# Microsoft Excel - Conditional formatting, finding duplicates

Tags: ms-office, formatting

I need to highlight duplicates in column A, but only if column B is equal to 10.

67890    10

67891    10

67891   20

67891   30

67892   10

67892   20

67894   10

67895   10

67891

In this example, what I want it to do is, as soon as I input the value on column A the cell automatically changes colour.

I have tried using sumproduct and countifs on conditional formatting, but it does not highlight the values.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is this a Apple problem ? In this example you do not have duplicates ?

Comment: This should be moved to Super User, it's not about Apple.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ....

Comment: This isn't off-topic. Unless the OP requires a Windows Excel version - it's just fine here. Even if it's more suited for another site, we don't migrate unless the OP asks for it or it's so clearly defined that it would fly on the new site. It might need to be closed as unclear since there are no version information for the OS or the spreadsheet software, but even then - someone could explain how to do this in numbers or excel even without that detail. Thanks for the flags, but this isn't good enough to migrate to another site.

Comment: @bmike IMHO this question is OS-agnostic, i.e. the commands would be the same on Excel for OS X and Excel for Windows. It has much higher chance to be solved on SO.

Comment: If someone with enough rep on SO or SU flags this with a link to their chat room saying this won't be closed immediately, I would migrate it. As it stands, I'm not going to just push it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution; it's not "pretty", but it works. Unfortunately, it is a bit hard to describe, so I'll make an
[example file](http://bit.ly/1hj8vDs) with explanations available, instead. In short, it uses

- a "helper cell" the locate and mark duplicates
- Excel's `use a formula to determine which cells to format` Conditional Formatting option to then color the original cells

Comment: The link is broken